# Cassandra Read , Read repair

Tags: cassandra

Scenario: Single data centre with replication factor 7 and read consistency level quorum.

During read request fastest replica gets a data request. But How many remaining replicas send the digest.

Q1 : Does all remaining (leaving fastest replica) replicas send the digest to coordinator. and the fastest 3 will be considered to satisfy the consistency. OR only  3 ((7 / 2 + 1) - 1(fastest) = 3) replicas will be chosen to send the digest.

Q2 : In both the case how read repair will work. How many and which nodes will get in sync after read repair runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from this excellent blog post which you should absolutely read: https://academy.datastax.com/support-blog/read-repair

There are broadly two types of read repair: foreground and background.  Foreground here means blocking -- we complete all operations before returning to the client.  Background means non-blocking -- we begin the background repair operation and then return to the client before it has completed.

In your case, you'll be doing a foreground read-repair as it is performed on queries which use a consistency level greater than ONE/LOCAL_ONE. The coordinator asks one replica for data and the others for digests of their data (currently MD5).  If there's a mismatch in the data returned to the coordinator from the replicas, Cassandra resolves the situation by doing a data read from all replicas and then merging the results.

This is one of the reasons why it's important to make sure you continually have anti-entropy repair running and completing. This way, the chances of digest mismatches on reads are lower.

Comment: In this case only 3 other nodes will be asked for digest to return? If yes how these 3 nodes will be chosen.

Comment: It will get a digest from all replicas. So it'll get 1 replica and 6 digests in your case.

Comment: so the fastest 3 digest reaching at coordinator  will be considered to check consistency others will we discarded.?

Comment: Q2: And if digests dosen't match for (fastest 4 digests) from how many replicas data will be retreived to get the latest data? Q3 : AND on which nodes this latest data will be written as a part of read repair?

Comment: This link no longer works